# Reset Token Parameter Leads to 404

Tags: reactjs, react-router, asp.net-identity, http-status-code-404

I am using reactjs + react router + iis

I am trying to do a password reset so my url lookslike

```
https://www.example.com/forgotPassword/CfDJ8BocAWQJpDVCswirwjHYLWRCG6zZTSxopJgdO3DDm4aO3g3PDFOjmENf6aTbq4qNUF6lMQuOot%2f1e1xZYdkM%2fV9%2bvatM6UBYNBJsZRBuiNnvnX2dPnMv8ANqg56Q2jaCXfVvW4Q%2fwGDDud28NJsFPQIBcb%2bsTnnu%2f22qwfEODpXk4e1BB8VdJWXwzEy8r1F9dq4iptdVEAf5thdUn4lMMpxsKW5r63QLCnn19GPhUcQA
```

On localhost it works great, on production I get a 404

If I do this on production

```
https://www.example.com/forgotPassword/1414
```

Works great as well. So I am guessing it is something with the token, I tried url encoding it as that was a problem.

My route

```
   <Route exact path="/forgotPassword/:token" component={ResetPasswordComponent} />
```

for whatever reason something in the token string(if I shorten it down, it works) is making it think that it is a page

[image]

edit

if I do this

```
CfDJ8BocAWQJpDVCswirwjHYLWRCG6zZTSxopJgdO3DDm4aO3g3PDFOjmENf6aTbq4qNUF6lMQuOot
```

Page loads, it does not like the %2 in the token.

Edit

I am using the MS identity library and I am using this method from the UserManager

```
userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(employee)
```

Comment: Can you please show how you're handling the token in the router?

Comment: @SterlingArcher done.

Comment: what version of react-router are you using?

Comment: @DiogoSgrillo - version 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Yes, problem is with your token. It happened to me once, when I was using `base64encode` to create token, and there was some `/` symbols etc. which were giving me 404 error.

There is an answer about best practices to generate forget password token, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013672/best-practice-on-generating-reset-password-tokens) to generate your token more safely.

Comment: I don't see any slashes even when I tried an online base64 decoder. The problem is that I am using asp.net identity this is what it generates for me, I am not generating the token myself.

Comment: What I am trying to say that problem is not with `react-router` and you know this, try different ways of generating the token, maybe generate it by yourself instead of using asp.net identity.

Comment: do you have an example on how to generate it myself? It is hard to find information on identity.

Comment: Here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643735/how-to-generate-a-unique-token-which-expires-after-24-hours). Just don't use `base64` encoding, use something like `md5`.

Comment: Well the problem is I am using asp.net identity core, with this one line of code I get the token: userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(employee)  if I don't use it I will have to essentially roll out my own thing what kind of defeats the purpose of using the toolkit. It is written by Microsoft not me.

Comment: You should write it yourself or read documentation carefully. Problem obviously is not with `react-router` or check .NET's routes or IIS's configuration